# Generating a CSR with next-generation Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) using mmc

Tags: windows-server-2016, csr, mmc

So...following the recommendations found [here](https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/1565/SHA256-and-Cryptographic-Service-Provider-Types), my goal is to get a code-signing certificate which uses the "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" (type 24) CSP.

Using Microsoft Management Console (mmc), and following[DigiCert's instructions](https://www.digicert.com/ecc-csr-creation-ssl-installation-microsoft.htm), which , I'm trying to create a custom CSR with this CSP type.

My problem is that, in the 'Private Key' tab, I'm unable to select the provider I need - the checkbox is grayed-out, and below is the following message:

*"The selected cryptographic service provider (CSP) cannot be used because a cryptography next generation (CNG) provider is required. Select a CNG provider and try again"*

I verified the existence of this provider using 'certutil -csplist'

Any ideas?

My machine is Windows Server 2016

Comment: When you start the process make sure you set the template to "LEGACY KEY" instead of "CNG KEY".

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and  figured out there are two places that limits the items displayed in CSP listbox

**1'st Place:**

[image]

**2'nd Place:**

[image]